# Div doesn't collapse while other div expands bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried all the answers posted previously on same type of question. Basically i want these two buttons two be in a line and only one of them should collapse at a time.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#sample1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="sample1" data-parent="#accordion">Sample 1</a>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#sample2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="sample2" data-parent="#accordion">Sample 2</a>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="collapse" id="sample1">
      <h1> here comes the sample1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="sample2">
      <h1> here comes the sample2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you added some CSS ??

Comment: So why not trying to do it?

Comment: @Ashishsah nope, not at all

Comment: Try using #sample1

Comment: Can you upload your code at jsbin.com by linking your bootstrap files too...

Comment: Open https://jsbin.com and paste the code there

Comment: i just made a working snippet of your question adding the necessary libraries to run it ;)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gahesatoru/edit?html,output @Ashishsah

Comment: i think that the buttons are toggling data quite fine...so what do you want to do

Comment: @G-Cyr please show me that

Comment: hmmmm i jsbin you need to add jQuery

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tikajukexe/edit?html,output

Comment: @Ashishsah only one button should toggle data at a time, right now if i click both buttons, both of them show their data

Comment: it is working corectly, what changes you've made? @Ashishsah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151988/discussion-between-pyrogrammer-and-ashish-sah).

Comment: have a look at down in my answer just added few classes to your button and js to handle click event

Comment: it's simple and easy to understand for starters...like us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Bootstrap v3 implements the accordion is somewhat of a blackbox (unless you really dig into the logic of the JS behind the scenes). However, this is what I understand based on some testing:

1. The controls can be arbitrarily nested
2. The accordion elements must be wrapped by a `<div>` with the class of `.panel`
3. The wrapper divs must be:

   - siblings of each other and
   - the direct descendent of the element specified in `data-parent` attribute (e.g. `#accordion` in your example), without any additional nesting

With that in mind, here are some changes you can make to your original DOM:

1. Move the `#accordion` ID to the wrapper of the panels
2. The controls can be positioned **anywhere on the page**, as long as `data-toggle="collapse" and`data-parent="#accordion`" is declared ;)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--
  Controls can be arbitrarily nested, no problem
  As a proof-of-concept, I have nested them three <div>s deep :) 
-->
<div><div><div>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#sample1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="sample1" data-parent="#accordion">Sample 1</a>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#sample2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="sample2" data-parent="#accordion">Sample 2</a>
</div></div></div>

<div id="accordion" class="accordion-group">

  <!-- Panel elements must be direct child of data-parent (#accordion) -->
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="collapse" id="sample1">
      <h1> here comes the sample1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <div class="collapse" id="sample2">
      <h1> here comes the sample2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you look at this :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".b1").click(()=>{
$("#menu2").hide();
$("#menu1").show();
 });
  $(".b2").click(()=>{
$("#menu2").show();
$("#menu1").hide();
})
```

});

https://jsbin.com/tikajukexe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: i hope that it helps you out

Comment: hey is this result you want :

Comment: are you telling that my jsbin code is not working..but I can clearly see the data-toggling here easily

Comment: yeah this is working at jsbin.com 
but when  i enter this script in my page, it is not working

Comment: remeber you add jquery before all your script files as i have done in jsbin and their must be some silly mistake figure it out and add the upper code in script,js or between ``` <script></script> ``` tag.

Comment: as that works in jsbin that will work in your system too ;)

Comment: well if it was helpful to you upvote my ans...figure it out there must be some silly mistake...thanks

Comment: i'm putting the jquey file  above all, i've seen there is no mistake 
please help buddy

Comment: can you upload all your code on jsbin ...if its small??

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with my jquery file, i copy pasted the code there and it worked, thanks buddy

Comment: you are welcome...don't forget to mark the ans as the right ans... ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151990/discussion-between-pyrogrammer-and-ashish-sah).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the default bootstrap collapse. 
What you can do is add a new jquery action like the following:

```
    $(document).on("click", "a[href='#sample1']", function() {
        if ($("#sample2").is(":visible")) {
            $("a[href='#sample2']").trigger("click");
        }
    });
    $(document).on("click", "a[href='#sample2']", function() {
        if ($("#sample1").is(":visible")) {
            $("a[href='#sample1']").trigger("click");
        }
    });
```

What this does is if one is visible when you click the other it triggers the collapse of the other to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would show you a generic way to do it with JQ

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function DataBindMenu(container){
 var menuButtons = $(container).find("a[type='button']");
 menuButtons.click(function(){
 $(container).find(".collapse").hide("slow"); // collapse all;
 // now lets view the right sample
 var sampleId = $(this).attr("aria-controls");
 $("#" + sampleId).show("slow");
 
 });

}

DataBindMenu("#accordion");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#sample1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="sample1" data-parent="#accordion">Sample 1</a>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#sample2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="sample2" data-parent="#accordion">Sample 2</a>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="collapse" id="sample1">
      <h1> here comes the sample1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="sample2">
      <h1> here comes the sample2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help you somehow, i never like to work with bootstrap